# how to set an int value to a string in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a value in a table that is currently an int and I want to pass those variables to a table on a webpage but I want to change those values to actual names instead of numbers is there a way to do that by setting a scope in the controller and then pushing that string to the html?

for example:

This would be the html code for the table row and head and then the table data.

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "x in names">
        <td>{{ x.bar }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I don't know the syntax for creating a scope for this in angular and then pushing that to the html or where it would go.

The table currently shows a 1 in the place of bar. I want it to actually say bar but register as 1. I don't know if that makes any sense.

I've seen some where they put

```js
app.filter('thisfilter', function() {
    return function (bar)

    if((bar) || bar < 1){
        return status_options;
    }else{
        var lastdigit = bar % 100;

        if(lastdigit === 1){
            return 'audi'
        } else if(lastdigit === 2){
            return 'bmw'
        } else if(lastdigit === 3){
            return 'mercedes'
        } else if(last digit === 4){
            return 'lexus'
        }
    }
}
```

and then they plug that back into the html

```html
<td>{{ x.foo | thisfilter }}</td>
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't type the variable. From string to number : `n = +s`, and from number to string : `s = \`${n}\`` (or `s = '' + n`)

Comment: oh okay so basically its impossible?

Comment: Where did I say that ? AngularJS was a long time ago for me, but conversion is either implicit or very easy.

Comment: If I'm understanding, the value is 1, but you want to display it as 'bar'. You don't actually want to change the value, you just want to change how it's displayed. If that's the case a filter would be the way to go.

Comment: oh thats what its called? okay I'll look up filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very contrived example to show the use of a filter to display text in place of a numeric value.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('valueToText', () => {
    return (input) => {
      switch (input) {
        case 1:
          return 'bar';
        case 2:
          return 'foo'
        default:
          return input;
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.names = [{
      value: 1
    }, {
      value: 2
    }, {
      value: 2
    }, {
      value: 'foobar'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.value | valueToText}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```